# Magento 2 System Log Errors

Tags: magento2, layout

Just had a look at the `var/log/system.log` file and surprised to see the number of errors. I cleaned up the file and refreshed the website and it logged following errors:

> [2016-10-12 14:27:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header.panel.wrapper' element cannot be added as child to 'header.container', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2016-10-12 14:27:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header-wrapper' element cannot be added as child to 'header.container', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2016-10-12 14:27:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'navigation.sections' element cannot be added as child to 'page.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2016-10-12 14:27:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'top.container' element cannot be added as child to 'page.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2016-10-12 14:27:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' element cannot be added as child to 'page.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2016-10-12 14:27:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'footer' element cannot be added as child to 'footer-container', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2016-10-12 14:27:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2016-10-12 14:27:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2016-10-12 14:27:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2016-10-12 14:27:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header.panel.wrapper' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header.container' and '' respectively. [] []
>   [2016-10-12 14:27:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'navigation.sections' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'page.top' and '' respectively. [] []

Same behavior on a fresh installation with no custom theme!
Any idea to why these layout errors!!

Answer (score 5):

From what i can tell the issue seems to be due to messy layouts and that are not getting moved or rendered correctly on certain pages.

The examples i have looked into so far is the `catalog.compare.sidebar` and `sale.reorder.sidebar` which are in the **Magento Catalog** module `default.xml` layout file however on the product page there is no sidebar so these fail to render. I believe this is default behaviour however as there is no sidebar on product pages and so this error is happening on even vanilla Magento installations.

So far i have tried removing the block from the product page but this does not help the error. Only thing i can think is to remove the block from the `default.xml` within a custom theme and add back into each page type individually on pages that do contain the sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

An update on my findings on the above issue, it was reported to Magento team on Github in [this thread](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3507). Magento are denying the fact that there is an issue (surprise) and have closed the ticket. I have stopped worrying it now because everything works on the website normally. The only thing bugging me is the ever increasing size of stystem.log file. I don't want to disable system logs so I'll try to find a way to clean the logs regularly so I still have access to latest reported issues in the file. RIP layout errors.